# Steps for setting up peers on different systems for Hyperledger fabric v1 (Node-SDK)

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

At present, we have done the set-up of Hyperledger fabric V1 network, which is running with 1 ordering service and 2 peers on single system. And our client application makes gRPC calls via NODE-SDK. Now we want to extend our application configuration to different physical systems where ordering service will run on one system and peers (peer 1 & peer 2) will run on two other systems.

Please someone provide with steps to achieve this type of setup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hyperledger Cello is also focused on enabling this sort of deployment. In particularly the [Ansible driver](https://github.com/hyperledger/cello/tree/master/src/agent/ansible).

Comment: Thanks for your response do you have any sample set up running on ansible?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, but I will ask around to see if any were preserved that could be turned into samples.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this script: https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment

It installs a distributed installation of fabric with solo orderer and a few peers, on several machines.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. We tried as per your URL and able to execute deploy.sh up to "Creating channel" step, but failed at step "Joining peers to channel" with following error:

Error: Error getting endorser client channel: PER:404 - Error trying to connect to local peer 
/home/dev/work/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common/common.go:116 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common.GetEndorserClient
... 
...
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:192 runtime.main
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2087 runtime.goexit
context deadline exceeded

Any clues please

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. The peer log is as below: 

[main] main -> ERRO 001^[[0m Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP from directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/sampleconfig/crypto: err The supplied identity is not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.hrl.ibm.il")

Comment: right, as I suspected - the peer is down.
I suggest you just delete the peer's sampleconfig directory and re-execute the deploy.sh script.

Comment: We are able to pass joining channel. Now we are getting error in Instantiating chaincode error as below peer.out:
[ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 03a^[[0m Failed connecting to localhost:7050 , error: context deadline exceeded
[deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 03b^[[0m Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [localhost:7050]
[deliveryClient] try -> WARN 03c^[[0m Got error: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [localhost:7050] ,at 1 attempt. Retrying in 1s

Comment: sigh...
do what you did to the peers, to the orderer too, and re-deploy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We applied the same approach to order, but getting the same result.

Comment: what's your TZ? ping me on chat.hyperledger.org and I'll try to help when I have time